# How to add extra data to the messages going to elasticsearch in fluentd

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, fluentd

I have setup `elasticsearch` and `fluentd` on my machine. I have written a basic configuration file which is monitoring a log file and sending the logs to `elasticsearch`. Below is the configuration file:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /home/user/log.json
  pos_file /home/user/log.json.pos
  format json
  time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
  tag first
</source>

<match *first*>
  @type elasticsearch
  hosts 192.168.60.118:9200
  user <username>
  password <password>
</match>
```

Below is the log message received on `elasticsearch`:

```
{
  "_index": "fluentd",
  "_type": "fluentd",
  "_id": "2987",
  "_version": 88,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "DataNumber": "030",
    "DataId": "MMX56",
    "DataCount": 87,
    "Status": "Done"
  },
  "fields": {
     "Created": [
      "2018-06-11T05:27:20.278Z"
     ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1528694840278
  ]
}
```

With the above message, I also want to add other information like the `machine number`, `floor number` which has generated this data and other stuff. I cannot hardcode this details in the code which is generating these logs. So I am looking for a way to add these details in the fluentd configuration file so that every outbound message to `elasticsearch` is appended with `machine number` & `floor number`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [record](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/filter_record_transformer):

```
<record>
    hostname "#{Socket.gethostname}"
    tag ${tag}
</record>
```